# Problems with html anchors changing the layout of the page

Tags: html, anchor

I am helping a client with his site, and one of the pages uses page anchors.  They work, however when active they cut out a large proportion of the top of the page by shifting the entire div up.

Here's the link http://hornblower-businesses.co.uk/hornblower-strategic-partners/

Answer (score 0):

You have `overflow:hidden` set on the main_body div.  Remove that rule or set it to `overflow:visible;`.  This will solve the div from shifting up.  However I think you may have another problem with the way the column divs are being floated/nested.